# ASP.NET MVC - call the same stored procedure from a different view/controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 5 different controllers / models / views. I have a button on each one of these views that will call a stored procedure. Depending on the controller, a different parameter is passed to the stored procedure.

I know how to call this stored procedure from each model class, and then use it in the view and controller. I do not know how to create and use this stored procedure as common functionality.

Here's a snippet of what I did - in each model class, I used ADO.NET Entity data model to get the stored procedure into the model.

In each view, I have:

```
<p style="margin-left: 2.5em">
    <br />
    <input type="button" style="height:40px; width: 160px;font-weight: bold;background-color:#00ffff; " value='@("Push to use stored procedure" )' onclick=" if (confirm ('Are you sure you want to do this?')){ window.location.href='@Url.Action("SPROCButton", "Controller1")' ;} " />
</p>
```

In controller1:

```
public ActionResult SPROCButton()
{
    try
    {
        db.uspCallTables("MyDB.temp.Table1");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

In other controllers, the only line that changes is the parameter. Is it necessary to have this stored procedure in each model and then call it?

Thank you
MR

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this. I propose to create a base controller and add all the common code.

The power of inheritance will not be seen in all its splendor in this example, but I think it will help you a lot to write common code.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
     public void callSP(string theParameter){
        db.uspCallTables(theParameter);
     }
}
```

then, your Controller1 , as follows:

```
public class Controller1 : BaseController
{
   public ActionResult SPROCButton()
   {
      try
      {
        callSP("MyDB.temp.Table1");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(e);
         throw;
      }
   }
}
```

That way you 'll can add all common code in the parent class (BaseController.cs).
I want to clarify that I'm assuming that "db" contains the database context. For this to work for you, you must load the object "db" of the new BaseController class in the same way you did in your Controller1. I hope this help you. Let me know it! Regards.